# Get triggers/table names in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, trigger

How can I get a listing of all triggers for a database along w/ the table that it belongs to?

I assume that I need `pg_trigger` and `pg_tables` but I'm not quite sure how to join them together.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
select trg.tgname,
        CASE trg.tgtype::integer & 66
            WHEN 2 THEN 'BEFORE'
            WHEN 64 THEN 'INSTEAD OF'
            ELSE 'AFTER'
        end as trigger_type,
       case trg.tgtype::integer & cast(28 as int2)
         when 16 then 'UPDATE'
         when 8 then 'DELETE'
         when 4 then 'INSERT'
         when 20 then 'INSERT, UPDATE'
         when 28 then 'INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE'
         when 24 then 'UPDATE, DELETE'
         when 12 then 'INSERT, DELETE'
       end as trigger_event,
       ns.nspname||'.'||tbl.relname as trigger_table,
       obj_description(trg.oid) as remarks,
         case
          when trg.tgenabled='O' then 'ENABLED'
            else 'DISABLED'
        end as status,
        case trg.tgtype::integer & 1
          when 1 then 'ROW'::text
          else 'STATEMENT'::text
        end as trigger_level
FROM pg_trigger trg
 JOIN pg_class tbl on trg.tgrelid = tbl.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace ns ON ns.oid = tbl.relnamespace
WHERE trg.tgname not like 'RI_ConstraintTrigger%'
  AND trg.tgname not like 'pg_sync_pg%'
```

It doesn't include DDL triggers though.

Answer (score 2):

here is improved one, which gets trigger function with its namespace:

```
         SELECT trg.tgname as tigger_name,
                CASE trg.tgtype::INTEGER & 66
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'BEFORE'
                    WHEN 64 THEN 'INSTEAD OF'
                    ELSE 'AFTER'
                END AS trigger_type,
               CASE trg.tgtype::INTEGER & cast(28 AS INT2)
                 WHEN 16 THEN 'UPDATE'
                 WHEN 8 THEN 'DELETE'
                 WHEN 4 THEN 'INSERT'
                 WHEN 20 THEN 'INSERT, UPDATE'
                 WHEN 28 THEN 'INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE'
                 WHEN 24 THEN 'UPDATE, DELETE'
                 WHEN 12 THEN 'INSERT, DELETE'
               END AS trigger_event,
               ns.nspname||'.'||tbl.relname AS trigger_table,
               obj_description(trg.oid) AS remarks,
                 CASE
                  WHEN trg.tgenabled='O' THEN 'ENABLED'
                    ELSE 'DISABLED'
                END AS status,
                CASE trg.tgtype::INTEGER & 1
                  WHEN 1 THEN 'ROW'::TEXT
                  ELSE 'STATEMENT'::TEXT
                END AS trigger_level,
                n.nspname || '.' || proc.proname AS function_name
        FROM pg_trigger trg
         JOIN pg_proc proc ON proc.oid = trg.tgfoid
         JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = proc.pronamespace
         JOIN pg_class tbl ON trg.tgrelid = tbl.oid
         JOIN pg_namespace ns ON ns.oid = tbl.relnamespace
        WHERE 
          trg.tgname not like 'RI_ConstraintTrigger%'
          AND trg.tgname not like 'pg_sync_pg%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Start up `psql` with `-E`. That will show you the commands it issues. Then run `\dft` to show the triggers.

The SQL it generates is,

```
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  p.proname as "Name",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_result(p.oid) as "Result data type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as "Argument data types",
 CASE
  WHEN p.proisagg THEN 'agg'
  WHEN p.proiswindow THEN 'window'
  WHEN p.prorettype = 'pg_catalog.trigger'::pg_catalog.regtype THEN 'trigger'
  ELSE 'normal'
 END as "Type"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc p
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE (
       p.prorettype = 'pg_catalog.trigger'::pg_catalog.regtype
      )
  AND pg_catalog.pg_function_is_visible(p.oid)
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
ORDER BY 1, 2, 4;
```

That will return a table like this,

```
 Schema |        Name        | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type   
--------+--------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------
 public | checkauthtrigger   | trigger          |                     | trigger
 public | do_stupid_stuff    | trigger          |                     | trigger
 public | postgis_cache_bbox | trigger          |                     | trigger
(3 rows)
```